# Need help on solving this PDE, stuck applying the initial and boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I completed the separation of variables step but I am very confused on how to apply the initial any boundary conditions to solve the problem. Please give me some advice or help to go about solving this problem, thank you!

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bts4.png)

> **Problem 1: Solution to homogeneous PDEs by separation of variables**
>   a. Apply separation of variables to derive the general solution $u(x,t)$ to the following homogeneous PDE over the interval $0\leq x\leq 1$, with boundary conditions $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$:
>   $$u = c\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial t\,\partial x^2}$$
>   b. Find the particular solution with initial conditions $u(x,0)=1$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: The boundary conditions arise in selecting the eigenfunctions. The initial conditions determine the "Fourier coefficients" of the eigenfunctions in the expansion.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Since you did the separation of variables, you have something like $u(x,t) = a(x)b(t)$.  The condition that $u(0,t) = 0$ means that $a(0)b(t) =0$.  So you must have $a(0)=0$, because if you set $b(t) = 0$ it forces $u(x,t) =0$ and we have no use for the trivial solution.  Likewise the second condition gives us $a(1) =0$.  Similarly the initial condition says $b(0) =1$.

Answer (score 0):

a. Substituting $u(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$ into the PDE, we obtain
$$
f(x)g(t)=cf''(x)g'(t) \implies \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{g(t)}{cg'(t)}=\lambda. \tag{1}
$$
Depending on the sign of $\lambda$, the solution to $f''(x)=\lambda f(x)$ is
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
a\cos(kx)+b\sin(kx)&\text{if $\lambda=-k^2<0$}, \\
a+bx&\text{if $\lambda=0$}, \\
a\cosh(\kappa x)+b\sinh(\kappa x)&\text{if $\lambda=\kappa^2>0$}.
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$
The boundary conditions $f(0)=f(1)=0$ generally imply $a=b=0$, except if $\lambda=-n^2\pi^2\, (n\in\mathbb{N}^*)$, in which case $f(x)=b\sin(n\pi x)$. The corresponding solution to $g'(t)=\frac{1}{\lambda c}g(t)$ is $g(t)=g(0)e^{-t/(n^2\pi^2c)}$.
Since the PDE is linear, the general solution satisfying the given boundary conditions is the linear combination
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_ne^{-t/(n^2\pi^2c)}\sin(n\pi x), \tag{3}
$$
provided the series converges.

b. The particular solution satisfying the initial condition $u(x,0)=1$ for $0<x<1$ can be obtained from $(3)$ using the orthogonality relation
$$
\int_0^{1}\sin(m\pi x)\sin(n\pi x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{m,n}\quad(m,n\in\mathbb{N}^*). \tag{4}
$$
Thus,
\begin{align}
u(x,0)=1 &\implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin(n\pi x)\,dx=1 \\
&\implies \frac{1}{2}a_m=\int_0^1\sin(m\pi x)\,dx=\frac{1-(-1)^m}{m\pi}, \tag{5}
\end{align}
hence,
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2[1-(-1)^n]}{n\pi}e^{-t/(n^2\pi^2c)}\sin(n\pi x). \tag{6}
$$